# Extended CKEditor 5 toolbar appears cropped when editing a section-block

Tags: 10, layout-builder

Anytime I try to edit a Layout Builder section-block with an **expanded** CKEditor 5, the toolbar is cropped.

This is probably a bug and may have to do with Right to Left languages like Hebrew or Arabic, but how to cope with that anyway?

> [image: screenshot]

These CSS codes work in console but not from a CSS file.

```css
#drupal-off-canvas-wrapper {
    width: 600px !important;
}
```

```css
#drupal-off-canvas-wrapper {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This JavaScript code works in console but not from a JS file.

```js
window.setInterval( () => {
    if (window.location.href.includes('layout')) {
        document.querySelector('#drupal-off-canvas-wrapper').style.width = "600px";
    }
}, 1);
```

How to solve this problem or at least how to get the window to always be broader as I have tried with the CSS and JS?

Answer (score -1):

A workaround that solves this problem is running the following code with a user script manager (such as Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey).

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Drupal Layout Builder Broadening
// @match        https://DOMAIN_NAME.TLD/*

// ==/UserScript==

window.setInterval(()=>{
    if (window.location.href.includes('layout')) {
        document.querySelector('#drupal-off-canvas-wrapper').style.width = "600px";
    }
}, 1);
```